# Why does everyauth depend on session?

Tags: node.js, everyauth

I can authenticate with facebook and everyauth but it doesn't work without the session module plugged in. The error message is...

> Step getSession of `facebook` is promising: session ; however, the
>   step returns nothing. Fix the step by returning the expected values OR
>   by returning a Promise that promises said values.

I don't want my app to use session.

Is it using it to store the user id of the authenticated user? If so, surely it could just put it in a cookie and encrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) for cookie-based session if you're not willing to use express' session middleware.

Comment: Probably not very secure. I will stick with server side session for now. ASP.net does a good job of authentication cookies.